# Switch all windows between 2 monitors

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I use **2 monitors** (with same resolution) and sometimes I want to **change** the **position** of all **windows** to the **other monitor**, so that everything which is displayed on the left monitor will be afterwards on the right and vice versa. Does there exist a shortkey to do this with one click or is it possible to to this with a script.
I know the short key "Windows" + "->" or "<-" to move the actual window on the same and next monitor to the right or left and the better way for this "Windows" + "Shift" + "->" or "<-" to move the window directly to the other monitor. But I want this for all windows on both monitors at the same time.
Here is an example which I want.[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile? I have the same problem. When I unplug my external monitor, all windows automatically move to the primary monitor. But when I plug the external monitor in again, I have to move each window one by one.